# Copy table values from database locally to table from remote online database

Tags: c#, mysql

I have table named'cottages' which is from my database on localhost and I want to copy it to my table also named 'cottages' which is located on my remote database online. I am using Hostinger as my hosting. My code is working when I am copying table values from one database to another locally but not working when I try to use it from localhost to online database.

Here is my code:

```
string connstr1 = "", connstr = "", server = "localhost", db = "remace",     uid = "", pass = "";
string serverOnline = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx", dbOnline = "user", uidOnline = "u971615137_benj", passOnline = "password";
connstr1 = "SERVER=" + server + ";" + "DATABASE=" + db + ";" + "UID=" + uid + ";" + "PASSWORD=" + pass + ";" + "Allow Zero DateTime=" + true;
connstr = "SERVER=" + serverOnline + ";" + "DATABASE=" + dbOnline + ";" + "UID=" + uidOnline + ";" + "PASSWORD=" + passOnline + ";" + "Allow Zero DateTime=" + true;

MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(connstr1);
MySqlConnection con1 = new MySqlConnection(connstr);
con.Open();
con1.Open();

string query = "INSERT INTO u971615137_cesys.cottages select * from remace.cottages";
MySqlCommand com = new MySqlCommand(query, con);
if (com.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0)
{
     MessageBox.Show("SUCCESS!!!");
}
else
{
     MessageBox.Show("FAILED!!!");
}
con1.Close();
con.Close();
```

Comment: Umm, you probably shouldn't have posted both **DB server IP**, and the **login credentials**.

Comment: can someone help me with my problem ?

Comment: @CasteloBenjie What are you trying to do there? Your `cont1` connection doesn't do anything, you open it and then you close it again. What exactly is the problem and what is the error message you get from MySQL? Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] of the problem you have.

Comment: I am trying to copy table values of 'cottages' from my database on localhost to my table 'cottages' to my database online. My code above is working when I am copying tables vaues from different databases on localhost. But when I try do it to copy from localhost to online it does't not work anymore.

Comment: I just solved it by myself. thanks.